# IBM connections API update event

Tags: atom-feed, connection

I'm trying to update event created in community.
Here is the atom xml I send to the server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn" xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0">
   <id>urn:lsid:ibm.com:calendar:event:0eff8fdf-4e5c-48be-be9b-ff700b274576</id>
   <snx:eventInstUuid>0eff8fdf-4e5c-48be-be9b-ff700b274576</snx:eventInstUuid>
   <title type="text">Test event</title>
   <snx:location>Event location</snx:location>
   <snx:startDate>2015-10-22T14:00:00.000+03</snx:startDate>
   <snx:endDate>2015-10-22T15:00:00.000+03</snx:endDate>
   <snx:allday>0</snx:allday>
   <category scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type" term="event-instance"/>
   <content type="html">Event description</content>
</entry>
```

The problem is it updates all fields that allow update. But startDate and endDate are updated as there is no timezone offset info. It means if I set startDate to 14:00, it actually sets time to 14:00 minus 3 hours.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it's server side and generally the pattern is to set it to UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the connections code can parse the '+03' only if you write it as '+03:00' (the timezone, unless you set it to 'Z' for UTC) needs to have 6 characters)